# php code to update single file to many users in mysql at a time

Tags: php, mysql

How to upload a single file into various rows (selected by checkbox in html table) in a database using php.so that a file will be uploaded to the selected user rows in  mysql database.

Comment: What file? Image-file? What have you tried before? What have you thought off?

Comment: Please show what you tried? Show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Mmh.. Not sure if this is what you need, but:

```
$db = new MySQLi("host", "user", "pass", "db");  # DB connection.
$ids = implode(",", $_POST['ids']);  # Rows IDs.
$file = $db->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));  # Uploaded file contents, escaped.
# Please note that some further checks on POST data are strongly adviced.

$db->query("UPDATE `mytable` SET `file` = '{$file}' WHERE `id` IN ({$ids})");  # Query.
```

Obviously, this needs an appropriate `POST` request, and a MySQL table with columns setted properly.